# passing javascript global variable between embeded pages or from main to embed

Tags: javascript

i have a html page with 2 embed pages

```
<body>
    <embed src ="toolbar.html" type="application/xhtml+xml"  width="485px" height="60px">
    <embed src="editor.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="595px" height="842px">
</body>
```

the first is a toolbar (jquery ui)
the second is an xml page with svg in it.
both pages have scripts.
Is there any way to pass a variable defined in a script from the toolbar to the svg ?

or if that isn't possible:

is there any way to pass a variable defined in the current document to an embedded page ?

tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Turn the `embed` elements into `iframe` elements, don't forget the close tags.**

   The [W3 - Technical Review - HTML 5 - The `embed` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-embed-element) mentions

   > The embed element represents an integration point for an external (typically non-HTML) application or interactive content.

   so you should rather use `iframe` elements instead of `embed` elements, [which](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element) mentions:

   > The iframe element represents a nested browsing context.

   in which [a browsing context is defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context) as:

   > A browsing context is an environment in which Document objects are presented to the user.
2. **You can declaring a global variable in a script you use in the main page.**

   It is as simple as `var myvariable;`
3. **You can access the variable from within an iframe using `window.parent.myvariable`.**

   [The DOM object `window.parent` is defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent) as such:

   > Returns a reference to the parent of the current window or subframe.
   >
   > If a window does not have a parent, its parent property is a reference to itself.
   >
   > When a window is loaded in an `<iframe>`, `<object>`, or `<frame>`, its parent is the window with the element embedding the window.

   A shortened version is to use `parent.myvariable`, as `window` is the root DOM object.
4. **Make sure that the domains, protocols and ports of the different documents match.**

   Unless you want to be presented with a nasty error like:

   > Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL X from frame with URL Y.
   > Domains, protocols and ports must match.